# Android Horizontal 'Progress bar' style indicators

Tags: android, drawing, progress-bar

I need to create some 'bar graph' style indicators in an Android app I'm putting together.  I'm trying to determine the best way of approaching the problem.

Basically, I need to create this inside one of my views:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWaTT.jpg

This will be updating in real time as the values change when receiving data.  Does it make sense to do this with a horizontal progress bar, or am I better off trying to use canvas to draw the rectangles?

Is there a better, straight forward solution I should be using?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some more specific requirements, it'd be hard to say exactly what approach is appropriate. If your graphs must change in realtime, then how often the values change matter. If the values could change in a time period on the order of milliseconds and your graphs should reflect that smoothly, then you'll probably want to do some custom drawing with `Canvas`. On the other hand, if you only need an update every second or so, `ProgressBar` should work just fine and gives you a lot of functionality for free.

Comment: The data will be coming in quickly (so probably the order of milliseconds, right now I think I have it updating data every 100 milliseconds), but if it's a better solution to only have it update every second or couple of seconds, I don't mind having the display change only every few seconds.  Even though the data is coming in quickly, the display doesn't need to update as quickly to display the changes.